# "Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence'" error in Swift

Tags: swift, logical-operators

In other languages, I've done logical expressions like this one without any issues, but I'm having a tough time in Swift.

I want this to evaluate as true if appPurchased = false AND enabled = true AND the button equals either photoLibraryBtn or takeVideoBtn:

```
for button in buttonList {

    if appPurchased == false &&
        enabled == true &&
        button == photoLibraryBtn |
        button == takeVideoBtn {

        continue

    }

    button.isEnabled = enabled
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = enabled
    button.alpha = alpha

}
```

I get the error "Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence'", which I can find no results on Google. I also don't see examples such as mine in Swift, so I'm thinking they did away with the single "|" pipe character, and you're only supposed to use the double pipe "||", but in a certain order. However, I don't want the if statement to pass as true if appPurchased = false, enabled = true, button = photoLibraryBtn OR button = takeVideoBtn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `||`, not `|`. `||` is "logical or". `|` is "bitwise or".

And when you mix `||` and `&&`, you need parentheses to avoid any ambiguity.

Based on your description, you want:

```
if appPurchased == false &&
    enabled == true &&
    (button == photoLibraryBtn ||
    button == takeVideoBtn) {

    continue
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
if !appPurchased &&
    enabled &&
    (button == photoLibraryBtn ||
    button == takeVideoBtn) {

    continue
}
```